# Checking for Last Page in QWeb Reports in Odoo

Tags: odoo, qweb

Odoo v8 uses Qweb and we need to print the terms and conditions of sale on the last page of the invoice.

As I understand we need to test that it is the last page of the report and print some static HTML on this page.

Does anyone know how to test the last page and remove the header and footer from it to achieve what I am trying.

Or even another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In last version of odoo, version 8 (or saas-6), to enable special class names to do special things (as for instance a 'last-page' class name to trigger visibility), you should only modify `report` module, in `static/src/js/subst.js`, and add this code to the `subst` function:

```
var operations = {
    'last-page': function (elt) { elt.style.visibility = (vars.page === vars.topage) ? "visible" : "hidden"; },
};

for (var klass in operations) {
    var y = document.getElementsByClassName(klass);
    for (var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) operations[klass](y[j]);
}
```

In the QWEB `ir.ui.views` used by your report, you can then add anywhere (header, body, footer), code with:

```
<div class="last-page">
    My content only displayed if on last page.
<div>
```

**EDIT**: An OpenERP/Odoo addon to add this magic class `last-page` easily was implemented as an example: https://github.com/0k/report_extended